# Artifactory Security Header Implementation

Tags: https, xss, artifactory

The Artifactory application has a response header "x-xss-protection:1;-mode=block"

We currently need to change the header to "x-xss-protection:0"

Can anyone please suggest how to implement this? I need to change this as per our security instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Nginx as reverse proxy can you try adding header in the config file /etc/nginx/site_enabled/artifactory.conf <<add_header "X-XSS-Protection" "0; mode=block";>>

Using nginx web server instructions

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+NGINX